# JS: Iterate through divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 div elements, all with class='item'.

Im catching them with: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("item");`

Now I want to make disappear that div, which was mouseovered.

https://jsfiddle.net/LqsLbrco/1/

But it doesn't work as it supposed to do. Because all elements are disappearing, not only this which was hovered.

**Edit**: My point is that the `modal` div appear (the pink box) when the `item` div is hovered. Check out the new jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LqsLbrco/10/

There's a div behind the blue boxes, I want him to appear when the user hovers the blue box.

Comment: `$(this).css(...)`

Comment: Should be basic stuff, especially when using jQuery -> https://jsfiddle.net/LqsLbrco/2/

Comment: I forgot about `this`. Damn. Thank you guys! @zerkms Please make a full answer so I will accept it as the best answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you want, or will accept, a jQuery based answer, please [edit] your question to include the [tag:jquery] tag. Without that tag, or other indication in the question that jQuery is acceptable, posting a jQuery based solution to a Question tagged [tag:javascript] is inappropriate (and will often be down-voted).

Comment: Your code has a bug  / coded wrong, Even though you are trying to iterate on each element, you are actually using the collection $(x) as your selector and there isnt any use of k at all in your for loop.

Comment: Please check it out again, I've edited the post.

Comment: @adeneo Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it in jQuery, you could just do this.

Modified the markup to accommodate the requirements.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".container .item").bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    $(event.target).find(".modal").show();
  });

  $(".container .modal").bind("mouseleave", function(event) {
    $(event.target).hide();
  })
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.modal {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm having little troubles with your code, because it affects other elements in `modal` div. :( Elements like spans and <a> are disappearing from div after clicking it.

Comment: would you mind posting in a fiddle / code snippet of your code?